# How to verify a file has been downloaded on my downloads directory on windowsd 10?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have automated a test script in selenium and c# whereby I click on an icon and it downloads a pdf file.  I do not know the name of this file, so what I need is confirmations its been downloaded, the file name and then it deletes the file?

I have done some research and found some code but it doesn't work.  Here is the latest code I have found but all it tells me in "files" is the number of pdf files in my directory.

```
string fileName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Don't know file name"];
string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");

DirectoryInfo downloadDir = new DirectoryInfo(pathDownload);
FileInfo[] files = downloadDir.GetFiles("*.pdf");
var file = files.Where(x => x.Name.Replace(" ", "") == fileName + ".pdf").FirstOrDefault();
fileName = file.FullName;
```

Comment: why not use file.exists?

Comment: file gives me null

Comment: Are you executing the program as administrator ? it does require in some cases privileges, and if you dont provide them it will give you null

Comment: Its my own local machine so I guess yes

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants to know I have figured it out.  So here is the code to confirm file has been downloaded and exists and then its deleted:

```
     string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
            string pathDownload = Path.Combine(pathUser, "Downloads");
            DirectoryInfo downloadDir = new DirectoryInfo(pathDownload);
            FileInfo[] files = downloadDir.GetFiles("*.pdf");
            var filename = files[0].FullName;
            string getFileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
            if (File.Exists(filename))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file has been downloaded successfully");
                Console.WriteLine("The filename is: " + getFileName);
            }
            File.Delete(filename);
```

Hope it helps someone.